# Why my protocol handler registered cannot trigger chrome app's url_handlers directly?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

To launch my chrome app, I set a url_handlers in the manifest.json as below:

```
  "url_handlers": {
    "view": {
      "matches": [
        "http://test.view.com/start.html*"
      ],
      "title": "view"
    }
  }
```

So now when I open the link "http://test.view.com/start.html*", the chrome app can be started successfully.
Then I register protocol handler to create my own url schema as below:

```
var url = "http://test.songli.com/start.html?data=%s";
window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler("web+view", url, "Test");
```

Here comes the question. When I open the link "web+view:data", the browser can open "http://test.view.com/start.html?data=blahblah". However, my chrome app cannot be started this time. Only after refreshing the page, app can be opened.
In fact, what I want is to open my chrome app directly by open the link "web+view:data". Is there something wrong in this way?

Comment: nothing wrong, it's just not planned to work this way.  
Protocol Handlers works only on websites (for now), looking forward to a fix to this as well...